# tslint complaining "statements must be filtered with an if statement" when using switch

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, tslint

Lets say I have the following method:

```
getErrorMessage(state: any, thingName?: string) {
    const thing: string = state.path || thingName;
    const messages: string[] = [];
    if (state.errors) {
        for (const errorName in state.errors) {
            switch (errorName) {
                case 'required':
                    messages.push(`You must enter a ${thing}`);
                    break;
                case 'minlength':
                    messages.push(`A ${thing} must be at least ${state.errors['minlength'].requiredLength}characters`);
                    break;
                case 'pattern':
                    messages.push(`The ${thing} contains illegal characters`);
                    break;
                case 'validateCardNumberWithAlgo':
                    messages.push(`Card doesnt pass algo`);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return messages;
}
```

when I run

```
ng lint
```

I get the following error :

*for (... in ...) statements must be filtered with an if statement*

Having a look at similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40770425/tslint-codelyzer-ng-lint-error-for-in-statements-must-be-filtere) I don't think that answer would be applicable to my situation. After all switch statement sits in the category of if-else-if ladder.

tslint should consider switch statement as form of if statement but it doesn't?!

Comment: use if else instead of switch?

Comment: Would you suggest the same thing if I had 100 conditions to check?

Comment: I would actually suggest you refactor the inner for loop into something else. :) A method call, or maybe map over the errors array to create the list of error messages. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the JSLint error 'body of a for in should be wrapped in an if statement' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963102/what-does-the-jslint-error-body-of-a-for-in-should-be-wrapped-in-an-if-statemen)

Comment: check out that question, it's for JS but the same applies. It has nothing to do with the switch statement, but with the for .. in :)

Comment: @toskv I think the point is that the rule says that an `if` statement should come after the `for...in`, and a switch statement can be seen as a kind of `if` statement, yet it doesn't resolve the error.

Comment: I believe the point of the rule is to filter out any properties that come from the prototype chain of the object accidentally. i.e. it expects `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propName))`. Right now you cannot be sure that `required` exists directly on `state.errors` object or from a prototype of it.

Comment: @Saravana you are correct - that is the intention of the rule. But you can literally have any `if` statement and the error will go away - it doesn't check specifically for `hasOwnProperty`. So in that case, a `switch` statement could be seen as similar to any `if` statement. The `case` statements could even be targeting only the property names known not to be on the prototype.

Comment: @FrankModica you are right, maybe the switch statement is not really used for checking if an object has a property. :-/ Anyway I added an answer that gets by this rule by not using for .. in at all. :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This made me curious, so I checked out the [TSlint source code](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/rules/forinRule.ts) for this rule. It has a function called `isFiltered` which seems to only check for `ts.SyntaxKind.IfStatement`, not for `ts.SyntaxKind.SwitchStatement`.

```
function isFiltered({statements}: ts.Block): boolean {
    switch (statements.length) {
        case 0: return true;
        case 1: return statements[0].kind === ts.SyntaxKind.IfStatement;
        default:
            return statements[0].kind === ts.SyntaxKind.IfStatement && nodeIsContinue((statements[0] as ts.IfStatement).thenStatement);
    }

}
```

So unless you want to convert your object to an array, you'll need to use a fix from the link you provided. Either `Object.keys`, or an `if` statement:

```
    for (const errorName in state.errors) {
      if (state.errors.hasOwnProperty(errorName)) {
        switch (errorName) {
```

The interesting thing is that you can have any kind of `if` statement and the error will go away. There is no check to see if you are calling `hasOwnProperty`.

Answer (score 15):

The rule is meant to prevent you from accessing properties defined on the object prototype when using **for .. in**.

You can however refactor the code to just not use that, and make it easier to maintain and develop as well.

An example would be this:

```js
interface ErrorMessageFactory {
  (thing: string, state?): string
}

type Errors = 'required' | 'minlength' | 'pattern' | 'validateCardNumberWithAlgo'

let errorFactory: {[e in Errors]: ErrorMessageFactory} = {
  required: (thing) => `You must enter a ${thing}`,
  minlength: (thing, state) => `A ${thing} must be at least ${state.errors['minlength'].requiredLength}characters`,
  pattern: (thing) => `The ${thing} contains illegal characters`,
  validateCardNumberWithAlgo: (thing) => `Card doesnt pass algo`
}



function getErrorMessage(state: any, thingName?: string) {
  if (state.errors) {
    return state.errors.map((error) => errorFactory[error](thingName, state));
  }
  return [];
}
```

You can see a working snippet in the playground [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ErrorMessageFactory%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20(thing%3A%20string%2C%20state%3F)%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Errors%20%3D%20'required'%20%7C%20'minlength'%20%7C%20'pattern'%20%7C%20'validateCardNumberWithAlgo'%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20errorFactory%3A%20%7B%5Be%20in%20Errors%5D%3A%20ErrorMessageFactory%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20required%3A%20(thing)%20%3D%3E%20%60You%20must%20enter%20a%20%24%7Bthing%7D%60%2C%0D%0A%20%20minlength%3A%20(thing%2C%20state)%20%3D%3E%20%60A%20%24%7Bthing%7D%20must%20be%20at%20least%20%24%7Bstate.errors%5B'minlength'%5D.requiredLength%7Dcharacters%60%2C%0D%0A%20%20pattern%3A%20(thing)%20%3D%3E%20%60The%20%24%7Bthing%7D%20contains%20illegal%20characters%60%2C%0D%0A%20%20validateCardNumberWithAlgo%3A%20(thing)%20%3D%3E%20%60Card%20doesnt%20pass%20algo%60%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getErrorMessage(state%3A%20any%2C%20thingName%3F%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(state.errors)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20state.errors.map((error)%20%3D%3E%20errorFactory%5Berror%5D(thingName%2C%20state))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20return%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A).