# How to group object properties by there pattern structure?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I have a kind of complicated algorithm to write using Javascript.

I have a data structure like this:

```json
const data = [
  {
    some_fees_dent_0: true,
    some_fees_name_0: "junao",
    some_fees_name_1: "adhm",
    some_fees_name_2: "uio",
    some_fees_rate_0: "45",
    some_fees_rate_1: "1",
    some_fees_rate_2: "22",
    some_fees: [],                # HERE
    initial_fees: [],             # HERE
    initial_fees_dent_0: true,
    initial_fees_name_0: "james",
    initial_fees_name_1: "daiep",
    initial_fees_name_2: "moaip",
    initial_fees_rate_0: "7",
    initial_fees_rate_1: "11",
    initial_fees_rate_2: "88",
    initial_fees_type_0: "foo",
    initial_fees_type_1: "bar",
    initial_fees_type_2: "random",
  }
]
```

I want to achieve this:

```json
const data = [
  {
    some_fees: [
      {
        some_fees_name: "junao",  # was initially some_fees_name_0
        some_fees_rate: "45",     # was initially some_fees_rate_0
        some_fees_dent: true,     # was initially some_fees_dent_0
      },
      {
        some_fees_name: "adhm",   # was initially some_fees_name_1
        some_fees_rate: "1",      # was initially some_fees_rate_1
      },
      {
        some_fees_name: "uio",    # was initially some_fees_name_2
        some_fees_rate: "22",     # was initially some_fees_rate_2
      },

    ],
    initial_fees: [
      {
        initial_fees_name: "james",   # was initially initial_fees_name_0
        initial_fees_rate: "7",       # was initially initial_fees_rate_0
        initial_fees_type: "foo",     # was initially initial_fees_type_0
        initial_fees_dent: true,      # was initially initial_fees_dent_0
      },
      {
        initial_fees_name: "daiep",   # was initially initial_fees_name_1
        initial_fees_rate: "11",      # was initially initial_fees_rate_1
        initial_fees_type: "bar",     # was initially initial_fees_type_1
      },
      {
        initial_fees_name: "moaip",  # was initially initial_fees_name_2
        initial_fees_rate: "88",     # was initially initial_fees_rate_2
        initial_fees_type: "random", # was initially initial_fees_type_3
      },

    ],
  }
]
```

Basically what happened is the initial `data` array that include objects now only include only two fields: `some_fees` `initial_fees`.

The other fields were put together in the same object based on the last number on their `key`, Which can be considered as `index` differentiator.

Comment: I know you are using react, But what is related you question with `reactjs`...

Comment: I almost just ignored your question because of this tag (`reactjs`) ... Remove unnecessary (`reactjs`, `ecmascript-6`) tags,

Comment: @Nur thank you for taking  your time to help and yes i am removing react tag

Comment: @Nur yes, currently going through it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialized parent first (`some_fees`, `initial_fees`) then group them by there pattern...

```js
let data = [{ some_fees_dent_0: true, some_fees_name_0: "junao", some_fees_name_1: "adhm", some_fees_name_2: "uio", some_fees_rate_0: "45", some_fees_rate_1: "1", some_fees_rate_2: "22", some_fees: [], initial_fees: [], initial_fees_dent_0: true, initial_fees_name_0: "james", initial_fees_name_1: "daiep", initial_fees_name_2: "moaip", initial_fees_rate_0: "7", initial_fees_rate_1: "11", initial_fees_rate_2: "88", initial_fees_type_0: "foo", initial_fees_type_1: "bar", initial_fees_type_2: "random", }],
    groups = new Map,
    result = [];

for (let item of data) {
    let root = {}, entries = Object.entries(item);
    result.push(root);

    for (let [key, value] of entries)
        if (Array.isArray(value))
            root[key] = []; // initializing parent node

    for (let [key, value] of entries) {
        let [k0, k1, k2, k3] = key.split('_'),
            modefiedKey = `${k0}_${k1}_${k2}`,
            groupID = `${k0}_${k1}_${k3}`,
            group = groups.get(groupID);

        if (!k2) continue;
        if (group) group[modefiedKey] = value;
        else {
            let node = { [modefiedKey]: value }, parentNode = root[`${k0}_${k1}`];
            groups.set(groupID, node);
            if (parentNode) parentNode.push(node);
        }
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thats impressive, im getting this error `The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype` because of the use of `for (const key in item) {`, do you have a solution with an alternative and also last question...how would your remove `_number` for each key for the solution?

Comment: is it syntax error? And explain the schema of your data structure...

Comment: *how would your remove _number for each key for the solution?* I didn't understand you quesion, Pls explain

Comment: I think its related to this article `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963102/what-does-the-jslint-error-body-of-a-for-in-should-be-wrapped-in-an-if-statemen` where the answer was `First of all, never use a for in loop to enumerate over an array.` `The reason behind this is the following: each object in JavaScript has a special field called prototype.`

Comment: Sure, you see all the fields in the solution you provide? i want them to be `initial_fees_type: "random",` as an example for one of them instead of `initial_fees_type_2: "random",`. what happened is that i removed the suffix `_2`. I want the same thing for all of them.

Comment: ooh I didn't modify anything... And you didn't specified that pattern in your question... how do i know that this is a thing?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I have updated my question with the correct expected solution data structure in the section `I want to achieve this:` It would be very helpful if you could help me solve that and the error caused by using a for loop...in for array. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Wait 2m, I will update my answer, And I don't use jslint... It just a linting error ,

Comment: you can replace `_number`( regex: `/_\d/`) with empty string using regex. but you should use `${k0}_${k1}_${k2}` as key, Because `_number` could replace any part of key, like: `obj_prop_0type_0` would be `obj_proptype_0`

Comment: I see, thank you. any thought on the replacement of the `for loop..in` with something else?

Comment: I use `for..in loop`  for getting key from object (`data[0]`) you could use `for..of` loop, like `for( const [key,value] of Object.entries(item)) {  ...  }` I just update my answer, Happy hacking...

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if there might be some kind of more general solution to this sort of thing. The idea with `create_object_from_structured_key_entries` (which could probably be written a fair bit better) is that it'll take entries with 'structured' keys as per the example in the first console.log(), and then create an object with the appropriate structure. For your data there's a `create_structured_key` function to convert your keys to structured ones so that it'll run through create_object_from_structured_key_entries.

```js
const data = [{"some_fees_dent_0":true,"some_fees_name_0":"junao","some_fees_name_1":"adhm","some_fees_name_2":"uio","some_fees_rate_0":"45","some_fees_rate_1":"1","some_fees_rate_2":"22","some_fees":[],"initial_fees":[],"initial_fees_dent_0":true,"initial_fees_name_0":"james","initial_fees_name_1":"daiep","initial_fees_name_2":"moaip","initial_fees_rate_0":"7","initial_fees_rate_1":"11","initial_fees_rate_2":"88","initial_fees_type_0":"foo","initial_fees_type_1":"bar","initial_fees_type_2":"random"}];

const create_object_from_structured_key_entries = (entries) =>
  entries.reduce(
    (acc, [key, val]) => {
      let current_object = acc;
      const dot_parts = key.split('.');
      
      dot_parts.forEach((dot_part, i) => {
        const arr_parts = dot_part.replace(/]/g, '').split('[');
        const for_array = arr_parts.length > 1;
        const array_index = for_array ? +arr_parts[1] : null;
        
        if(!current_object[arr_parts[0]])
          current_object[arr_parts[0]] = for_array ? [] : {};
        
        if(for_array && !current_object[arr_parts[0]][array_index])
          current_object[arr_parts[0]][array_index] = {};
        
        if(i === dot_parts.length - 1) {
          if(for_array) {
            current_object[arr_parts[0]][array_index] = val;
          } else {
            current_object[arr_parts[0]] = val;
          }
          return;
        }
        
        if(for_array) {
          current_object = current_object[arr_parts[0]][array_index];
        } else {
          current_object = current_object[arr_parts[0]];
        }
      });
      
      return acc;
    }, {}
  );

const create_structured_key = (key) => {
  const [k0, k1, k2, k3] = key.split('_');
  if(!k2) return null;
  return k0 + '_' + k1 + '[' + k3 + ']' + '.' + k0 + '_' + k1 + '_' + k2;
};

const data_item_to_structured_object = (item) =>
  create_object_from_structured_key_entries(
    Object.entries(item)
      .map(([key, val]) => [create_structured_key(key), val])
      .filter(([key, val]) => key)
  );
  
const data_to_structured_object = (arr) => arr.map(data_item_to_structured_object);

console.log(create_object_from_structured_key_entries( Object.entries({
  'a.aa[0].aaa[1]': 'bob',
  'a.aa[0].ddd': 'fred',
  'a.bb.eee': 'jane'
}) ));

console.log(data_to_structured_object(data));
```